# outputting stdout and stdin for multiple files running simultaneously

Tags: linux, stdout, stdin

I have the following command which works on a bam file

```
reformat.sh in=test.bam out=stdout.fq primaryonly | reformat.sh in=stdin.fq out1=r1.fq.gz out2=r2.fq.gz interleaved addcolon
```

The idea here is to avoid writing the output of the first command(reformat.sh) to a file, which increases the overall speed.

I have several bam files in my current working directory and I want to run them on the cluster in parallel. How can I use stdout.fq and stdin.fq in the above command so that when multiple bam files are being processed simultaneously, stdout.fq/stdin.fq does not interfere with each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting very confused with file-name-extensions. There is no such thing. Not since MS-DOS and CPM. Microsoft's Windows still uses them to trigger actions in file-explorer, but they are just part of the file-name.

Therefore `stdout` and `stdout.fq` are different files. Also the name for `stdout` is `/dev/stdout`, and `stdin` is `/dev/stdin`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `reformat.sh` is written.

Often UNIX commands will use stdin and stdout if you do not give them any input/output:

```
reformat.sh in=test.bam primaryonly |
  reformat.sh out1=r1.fq.gz out2=r2.fq.gz interleaved addcolon
```

Other times they will accept - as a file name:

```
reformat.sh in=test.bam out=- primaryonly |
  reformat.sh in=- out1=r1.fq.gz out2=r2.fq.gz interleaved addcolon
```

In modern Bash you can use `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout`:

```
reformat.sh in=test.bam out=/dev/stdout primaryonly |
  reformat.sh in=/dev/stdin out1=r1.fq.gz out2=r2.fq.gz interleaved addcolon
```

To avoid conflicting names when running jobs in parallel I would build a function, that takes the names as arguments:

```
refo() {
  in="$1"
  out1="$2"1.fq.gz
  out2="$2"2.fq.gz
  reformat.sh in=/dev/stdin out=/dev/stdout primaryonly |
    reformat.sh in=/dev/stdin out1="$out1" out2="$out2" interleaved addcolon
}
```

And the call it like:

```
refo test.bam out
```

When that works you can parallelize over multiple `bam` files with:

```
export -f refo
parallel refo {} {.} ::: *.bam
```